# Text doesnt appear on screen when written to TextView object

Tags: android

Main activity onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    // Specify text size
    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(10);
    setContentView(textView);
```

Now i can use textView.append() and whatever i write appears on screen, great.

However, if i want to use a layout xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a_text_window"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How should i code the onCreate method so that i can set setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) and then use textView.append() in the same manner? I just want a window with the text in, so i can add some other buttons later.

Comment: could you please clarify more

Answer (score 1):

Try this to inflate your main.xml file and get the TextView.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    //Inflate your xml called main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_text_window);
    // Specify text size (ALREADY DONE IN XML)
    textView.setTextSize(10);
}
```

By the way, you can define your textsize in the xml file ! :)

Comment: First of all, i have to type:   

textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_text_window);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

I.E. a_text_window is saved in R.id instead of R.layout. Trying that however crashes the application

Comment: Of course it works :p If your haven't inflated your layout, you couldn't retrieve the items in it !